# How to let OCaml function returns a tuple containing a string and a function?

Tags: function, ocaml, return-value

Eventually what I want is what x represents:
`let x = (something, (myfunc1 para1));;`
so that when calling `x`, I get a tuple, but when calling `(snd x) para`, I will get a return value of `myfunc1 para`.

What I'm trying is like this:

```
let myfunc2 para1 para2 = 
  let myfunc1 para2 = ... in
  ( (fst para1), (myfunc1 para2) );;
```

And I want to call `myfunc2` like this:
`let x = myfunc2 para1` to get what I described above. However, what I get is just a function which when called with para1 will return a regular tuple, not a `(something, function)` tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a useless `para2` parameter in your definition. The correct way is:

```
let myfunc2 para1 = 
  let x = ... in
  let myfunc1 para2 = ... in
  ( x, myfunc1 );;
```

But it would help if we could speak about a concrete example. You are misunderstanding something obvious, but I do not know what.

Here is a concrete example. Suppose we want a function `f` which accepts a number `n` and returns a pair `(m, g)` where `m` is the square of `n` and `g` is a function which adds `n` to its argument:

```
let f n =
  let m = n * n in
  let g k = n + k in
    (m, g)
```

Or shorter:

```
let f n = (n * n, fun k => n + k)
```

Now to use this, we can do:

```
let x = f 10 ;;
fst x ;; (* gives 100 *)
snd x ;; (* gives <fun> *)
snd x 5 ;; (* gives 15, and is the same thing as (snd x) 5 *)
```

Now let us consider the following *bad* solution in which we make the kind of mistake you have made:

```
let f_bad n k =
  let m = n * n in
  let g k = n + k in
    (m, g k)
```

Now `f_bad` wants two arguments. If we give it just one, we will not get a pair but a function expecting the other argument. And when we give it that argument, it will return a pair of two integers because `(m, g k)` means "make a pair whose first component is the integer `m` and the second component is `g` **applied to `k`**, so that is an integer, too."

Another point worth making is that you are confusing yourself by calling two different things `para2`. In our definition of `f_bad` we also confuse ourselves by calling two different things `k`. The `k` appearing in the definition of `g` is not the same as the other `k`. It is better to call the two `k`'s different things:

```
let f_bad n k1 =
  let m = n * n in
  let g k2 = n + k2 in
    (m, g k1)
```

Now, does that help clear up the confusion?

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. This helps huge.